# Wen Intel 82599 ixgbe(PF) driver loaded with VMs (sriov_numvfs>0) and ixgbevf (VF) is loaded on VM, encountering an AER on the PF results in VF hang

Tags: error-handling, virtual-machine, virtual-functions, pci-e

Why does the Intel 82599 driver (ixgbe, PF) exhibit a behavior where, when loaded with virtual machine/s (with sriov_numvfs>0) and the ixgbevf driver (VF) is loaded on those virtual machines, encountering an AER (Advanced Error Reporting) on the PF results in VF hang without any corresponding log captured in VFs dmesg? Is there a solution to prevent VF hangs in such scenarios (here PF remains fully operational).

### I'm referring to the Linux kernel and OS as follows:

### user@user-B460MDS3HV2:~$ uname -r

```
5.15.0
```

### user@user-B460MDS3HV2:~$ lsb_release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

### The output of the lspci command on the PF is as follows:

user@user-B460MDS3HV2:~$ lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9b43 (rev 05)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 05)
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Thermal Controller
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Shared SRAM
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake HECI Controller
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 06d2
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06c2 (rev f0)
00:1b.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #21 (rev f0)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06bc (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b4 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0684
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH cAVS
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SMBus Controller
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SPI Controller
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (11) I219-V
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208B [GeForce GT 710] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 HDMI/DP Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5765 (rev 01)
**04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection (rev 01)**
04:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection (rev 01)
04:10.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599 Ethernet Controller Virtual Function (rev 01)
```

(Here, 04:00.0 and 04:00.1 are the interfaces of my Intel 10G NIC)

### Below is the information regarding the interface:

user@user-B460MDS3HV2:~$ sudo lspci -s 04:00.0 -vvv

```
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Ethernet Server Adapter X520-2
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-`
    `Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    Region 0: Memory at 4c500000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Region 2: I/O ports at 3020 [disabled] [size=32]
    Region 3: Memory at 4c700000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Expansion ROM at 4c280000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=1 PME-
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
        Masking: 00000000  Pending: 00000000
    Capabilities: [70] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=64 Masked-
        Vector table: BAR=3 offset=00000000
        PBA: BAR=3 offset=00002000
    Capabilities: [a0] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 512 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <64us
            ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset+ SlotPowerLimit 0.000W
        DevCtl: CorrErr+ NonFatalErr+ FatalErr+ UnsupReq+
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+ FLReset-
            MaxPayload 256 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 5GT/s, Width x8, ASPM L0s, Exit Latency L0s <1us
            ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp-
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 5GT/s (ok), Width x4 (downgraded)
            TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range ABCD, TimeoutDis+, NROPrPrP-, LTR-
             10BitTagComp-, 10BitTagReq-, OBFF Not Supported, ExtFmt-, EETLPPrefix-
             EmergencyPowerReduction Not Supported, EmergencyPowerReductionInit-
             FRS-, TPHComp-, ExtTPHComp-
             AtomicOpsCap: 32bit- 64bit- 128bitCAS-
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
             AtomicOpsCtl: ReqEn-
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
             EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES- TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, ECRCGenCap+ ECRCGenEn- ECRCChkCap+ ECRCChkEn-
            MultHdrRecCap- MultHdrRecEn- TLPPfxPres- HdrLogCap-
        HeaderLog: 00000000 00000001 00000002 00000003
    Capabilities: [140 v1] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-ff-ff-00-00-00
    Capabilities: [150 v1] Alternative Routing-ID Interpretation (ARI)
        ARICap: MFVC- ACS-, Next Function: 1
        ARICtl: MFVC- ACS-, Function Group: 0
    Capabilities: [160 v1] Single Root I/O Virtualization (SR-IOV)
        IOVCap: Migration-, Interrupt Message Number: 000
        IOVCtl: Enable+ Migration- Interrupt- MSE+ ARIHierarchy+
        IOVSta: Migration-
        Initial VFs: 64, Total VFs: 64, Number of VFs: 1, Function Dependency Link: 00
        VF offset: 128, stride: 2, Device ID: 10ed
        Supported Page Size: 00000553, System Page Size: 00000001
        Region 0: Memory at 000000004c704000 (64-bit, prefetchable)
        Region 3: Memory at 000000004c804000 (64-bit, prefetchable)
        VF Migration: offset: 00000000, BIR: 0
    Kernel driver in use: ixgbe
    Kernel modules: ixgbe
```

### The VFs BDF is attached through PCIe passthrough.
The output of the lspci command on the VF is as follows:

ubuntu@ubuntu-Standard-PC-Q35-ICH9-2009:~$ lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31/P35/P31 Express DRAM Controller
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Red Hat, Inc. QXL paravirtual graphic card (rev 04)
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Red Hat, Inc. QEMU PCIe Root port
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Red Hat, Inc. QEMU PCIe Root port
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Red Hat, Inc. QEMU PCIe Root port
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Red Hat, Inc. QEMU PCIe Root port
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Red Hat, Inc. QEMU PCIe Root port
00:02.5 PCI bridge: Red Hat, Inc. QEMU PCIe Root port
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801IB (ICH9) LPC Interface Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801IR/IO/IH (ICH9R/DO/DH) 6 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 02)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Red Hat, Inc. Virtio network device (rev 01)
02:00.0 Communication controller: Red Hat, Inc. Virtio console (rev 01)
03:00.0 SCSI storage controller: Red Hat, Inc. Virtio block device (rev 01)
04:00.0 Unclassified device [00ff]: Red Hat, Inc. Virtio memory balloon (rev 01)
05:00.0 Unclassified device [00ff]: Red Hat, Inc. Virtio RNG (rev 01)
**06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599 Ethernet Controller Virtual Function (rev 01)**
```

(Here, 06:00.0 is the interfaces on VM)

### Below is the information regarding the interface:

ubuntu@ubuntu-Standard-PC-Q35-ICH9-2009:~$ sudo lspci -s 06:00.0 -vvv

```
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599 Ethernet Controller Virtual Function (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82599 Ethernet Controller Virtual Function
    Physical Slot: 0-5
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Region 0: Memory at fe000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Region 3: Memory at fe004000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [70] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=3 Masked-
        Vector table: BAR=3 offset=00000000
        PBA: BAR=3 offset=00002000
    Capabilities: [a0] Express (v1) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <64ns, L1 <1us
            ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE- FLReset- SlotPowerLimit 0.000W
        DevCtl: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq-
            RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed unknown, Width x0, ASPM not supported
            ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp-
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk-
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed unknown (ok), Width x0 (ok)
            TrErr- Train- SlotClk- DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr-
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, ECRCGenCap- ECRCGenEn- ECRCChkCap- ECRCChkEn-
            MultHdrRecCap- MultHdrRecEn- TLPPfxPres- HdrLogCap-
        HeaderLog: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    Kernel driver in use: ixgbevf
    Kernel modules: ixgbevf
```

### I have configured and compiled the kernel to support AER injection.

user@user-B460MDS3HV2:~$ cat /boot/config-5.15.0 | grep AER

```
CONFIG_ACPI_APEI_PCIEAER=y
CONFIG_PCIEAER=y
CONFIG_PCIEAER_INJECT=y
```

### My grub command line optios are as floows

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="pcie_ports=native intel_iommu=on iommu=pt"
```

### I am using this standard Linux tool to inject the software-level error.

[Google] (https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/gong.chen/aer-inject.git/)

### After injecting the error (non-fatal)on PF (on BDF 04:00.0), here is the log where error recovery occurs successfullyon PF, but the VF hangs.

### PFs log:

```
...
...
(Added some debug prints)
`[22464.094873] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: saving config space at offset 0x30 (reading 0x0)
[22464.094877] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: saving config space at offset 0x34 (reading 0x50)
[22464.094880] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: saving config space at offset 0x38 (reading 0x0)
[22464.094883] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: saving config space at offset 0x3c (reading 0x10b)
[22464.094905] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: PME# enabled
[22464.111802] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: power state changed by ACPI to D3hot
[22484.225113] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: aer_inject: Injecting errors 00000000/00008000 into device 0000:04:00.0
[22484.225158] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: Uncorrected (Non-Fatal) error received: 0000:04:00.0
[22484.225163] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Uncorrected (Non-Fatal), type=Transaction Layer, (Completer ID)
[22484.225165] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0:   device [8086:10fb] error status/mask=00008000/00000000
[22484.225166] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0:    [15] CmpltAbrt             
[22484.225168] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0: AER:   TLP Header: 00000000 00000001 00000002 00000003
[22484.225171] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: broadcast error_detected message
[22484.225172] -------------->>>>---ixgbe io err detected---->>>>-------
[22484.225174] ---------detach device--------
[22484.289962] ---------ixgbe close--------
[22484.289967] ---------disable dev--------
[22484.289986] -------------->>>>---ixgbe io err detected---->>>>-------
[22484.289994] ---------detach device--------
[22484.355658] ---------ixgbe close--------
[22484.355663] ---------disable dev--------
[22484.355750] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: broadcast slot_reset message
[22484.355759] -------------->>>>---ixgbe io slot reset---->>>>-------
[22484.355781] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0: enabling bus mastering
[22484.355869] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0: restoring config space at offset 0x4 (was 0x100406, writing 0x100006)
[22484.355929] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0: saving config space at offset 0x0 (reading 0x10fb8086)
[22484.355952] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0: saving config space at offset 0x4 (reading 0x100406)
[22484.355965] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0: saving config space at offset 0x8 (reading 0x2000001)
[22484.355975] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0: saving config space at offset 0xc (reading 0x800010)
[22484.355994] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0: saving config space at offset 0x10 (reading 0x4c500008)
[22484.356003] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0: saving config space at offset 0x14 (reading 0x0)
[22484.356011] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0: saving config space at offset 0x18 (reading 0x3021)
[22484.356020] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0: saving config space at offset 0x1c (reading 0x4c700008)
[22484.356028] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0: saving config space at offset 0x20 (reading 0x0)
[22484.356051] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0: saving config space at offset 0x24 (reading 0x0)
[22484.356064] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0: saving config space at offset 0x28 (reading 0x0)
[22484.356083] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0: saving config space at offset 0x2c (reading 0xc8086)
[22484.356091] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0: saving config space at offset 0x30 (reading 0x4c280000)
[22484.356098] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0: saving config space at offset 0x34 (reading 0x40)
[22484.356106] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0: saving config space at offset 0x38 (reading 0x0)
[22484.356115] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0: saving config space at offset 0x3c (reading 0x10b)
[22484.420988] -------------->>>>---ixgbe io slot reset----else--->>>>-------
[22484.420995] -------------->>>>---ixgbe io slot reset---->>>>-------
[22484.421017] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1: enabling bus mastering
[22484.421105] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1: restoring config space at offset 0x4 (was 0x100406, writing 0x100006)
[22484.421207] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1: saving config space at offset 0x0 (reading 0x10fb8086)
[22484.421214] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1: saving config space at offset 0x4 (reading 0x100406)
[22484.421220] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1: saving config space at offset 0x8 (reading 0x2000001)
[22484.421226] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1: saving config space at offset 0xc (reading 0x800010)
[22484.421231] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1: saving config space at offset 0x10 (reading 0x4c600008)
[22484.421237] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1: saving config space at offset 0x14 (reading 0x0)
[22484.421243] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1: saving config space at offset 0x18 (reading 0x3001)
[22484.421248] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1: saving config space at offset 0x1c (reading 0x4c904008)
[22484.421254] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1: saving config space at offset 0x20 (reading 0x0)
[22484.421259] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1: saving config space at offset 0x24 (reading 0x0)
[22484.421264] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1: saving config space at offset 0x28 (reading 0x0)
[22484.421269] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1: saving config space at offset 0x2c (reading 0xc8086)
[22484.421275] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1: saving config space at offset 0x30 (reading 0x4c200000)
[22484.421280] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1: saving config space at offset 0x34 (reading 0x40)
[22484.421286] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1: saving config space at offset 0x38 (reading 0x0)
[22484.421291] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1: saving config space at offset 0x3c (reading 0x20a)
[22484.484968] -------------->>>>---ixgbe io slot reset----else--->>>>-------
[22484.484978] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: broadcast resume message
[22484.484984] -------------->>>>---ixgbe io resume---->>>>-------
[22484.611466] ---------- ixgbe open----------
[22484.611498] ---------- dev attched----------
[22484.611553] -------------->>>>---ixgbe io resume---->>>>-------
[22484.677281] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0f0: detected SFP+: 5
[22484.795454] ---------- ixgbe open----------
[22484.795487] ---------- dev attched----------
[22484.795586] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: device recovery successful
[22484.939510] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0f0: NIC Link is Up 10 Gbps, Flow Control: RX/TX
[22485.001449] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1 enp4s0f1: detected SFP+: 6
[22485.263514] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1 enp4s0f1: NIC Link is Up 10 Gbps, Flow Control: RX/TX
```

### VFs log during this:

```
...
...
...
[  322.159514] ixgbevf 0000:06:00.0: NIC Link is Down
```

And the VM hangs.

I'm not a PCIe expert. Please provide me with some insights into why this is happening and potential solutions to prevent VF hang when AER is triggered on the PF.